# Fortran execute_command_line runtime error, depends on memory consumption

Tags: bash, fortran, runtime-error

I am getting runtime errors when trying to create a directory using the execute_command_line intrinsic in Fortran. The error occurs both with Ifort (18.0.3 20180410) and gfortran (4.8.5).
Here is a minimal example that fails with whatever compile flags I use:

```
PROGRAM directory_test

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: cstat, estat, i, j
    CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: cmsg

    REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: field
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: fieldsize = 80000

    allocate(field(fieldsize,fieldsize))
    do j=1, fieldsize
        do i=1, fieldsize
            field(i,j) = real(i+j)
        end do
    end do

    call execute_command_line('mkdir -p newdir', WAIT=.true., EXITSTAT=estat, CMDSTAT=cstat, CMDMSG=cmsg)

    write(*,*) 'estat: ', estat
    write(*,*) 'cstat: ', cstat
    write(*,*) 'cmsg:  ', cmsg

END PROGRAM directory_test
```

Output ifort:
estat:            0
cstat:          124
cmsg:  Invalid command supplied to EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE

Output gfortran:
estat:   -520880432
cstat:            1
cmsg:  Termination status of the command-language interpreter cannot be obtained

**Here is the catch:** the program runs just fine as long as the array size is small enough. For me the threshold is about half of the physical memory used (adjust the value of "fieldsize" if you want to try the code). If the array is larger than that, the error occurs. If the array is smaller, the code executes without errors and the directory is created.
The machines I used to test this all have 2 physical CPUs  and 128GB-256GB of RAM.
What am I doing wrong?

OS: Linux, Opensuse 42.3
shell: bash
file system: Ext4

Edit: the issue is not exclusive to "execute_command_line()". Trying to do the same with "call system()" I get similar behaviour. The new directory is not created in cases where the original method fails with a runtime error.
Additional tests on smaller/older dual-socket machines down to 48GB of available RAM yield the same results. Some fail earlier, some need almost the entire physical memory occupied by the program to fail. Unfortunately I don't have a single-socket machine to test right now.

Comment: I happen to have the same OS version. I executed the code and it created the directory successfully.  But during the execution it used around 75% of my 32GB memory. Just the `cmsg` contained garbage, which is not surprising given `estat` and `cstat` were both 0. It was successful both in gfortran 4.8.5 and in ifort 16. On this machine I can't test any larger size.

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour for a 30GB array. When I tried runtime checks in ifort, it segfauletd, address sanitozer in GCC had insufficient memory. I had plenty of swap space available where other programs were sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE as well as the SYSTEM intrinsics are implemented on Linux is that first the process calls the fork() syscall, which creates a clone of the process. Then the child will call exec() which replaces that process with the new process to execute.

So even if the second forked process is very short-lived before it's replaced by the new exec()ed process, the system still needs sufficient virtual memory for both the original process and the forked child process. On Linux, if you have superuser access you can tune the limits (as a function of physical memory) with the various "overcommit" knobs.

If possible, one way to get around this problem is to call EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE before you allocate a lot of memory, or after you have deallocated it.

Comment: How much virtual memory does the child process need? The same amount the parent process currently uses? So the problem is triggered when the forking process exceeds half of the mem+swap?

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes, initially the fork()ed process is a clone of the parent, so it needs the same amount of memory. Linux by default allows overcommit, that is that the total virtual memory may exceed the physical mem + swap, but that can be configured (or disabled entirely) by the administrator.

Comment: The reason for overcommit in the first place is the fork+exec way of launching new processes; in most cases you don't need as much backing store as you have allocated virtual memory.  Occasionally overcommit is a bad choice and then the dreaded OOM killer chooses a victim process to kill, and people complain. But there's two coins to the argument..

Comment: Doing all filesystem-related stuff beforehand works indeed, it is the workaround I used so far...without actually knowing why it worked. just wished there was a real solution that does not limit me in such a way. But this is more a concern for my colleague who is very reluctant when it comes to changing part of his code *sigh

Comment: So what is the difference between a normal allocate and execute_command_line? Because there still is enough virtual memory to allocate new fields at the point where execute_command_line causes the error.

Comment: All right, I was able to get one of the codes in question running using /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory=2 and /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio=200. I will keep the risk associated with this in mind

Answer (score 1):

You also posted this in the [Intel Fortran for Linux forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/805993). Replies indicated that your array allocation was using up all available virtual memory, leaving insufficient memory for EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE or alternatives. Three different compilers all gave errors on your example - NAGfor was the most helpful with an "insufficient virtual memory" error.

Comment: This seems strange, the run finishes OK. And I had loads of space in swap in my tests.

Comment: My familiarity with Linux is minimal, but I know that there are limitations on address space based on kernel build parameters.

Comment: While this seems like a possible explanation, I still can't wrap my head around why the error occurs although there is still plenty of memory available. I'll go searching for processes that hog a lot of virtual memory when I get back to the office tomorrow. A workaround would be welcome.